# SQLServer2000 Constraints

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Is there any way to remove all forgeinKey and primary key contriants from 
Database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to build on Richard's code:

```
SELECT 
'ALTER TABLE ' + object_name(parent_obj) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + object_name(id),* FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype IN ('F', 'PK')
```

You can run the output in QA & watch your db churn as it turns your tables into heaps

Comment: Thanks like that we can do i have another option too
-- select 'Alter Table ' + Table_Name + ' Drop Constraint ' + Constraint_Name 
-- from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where Constraint_type like 'F%'
-- union
-- select 'Alter Table ' + Table_Name + ' Drop Constraint ' + Constraint_Name 
-- from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where Constraint_type like 'P%'

because i need to remove first forgeinkey and after primary key

Comment: Done below is Query 
select 'Alter Table ' + Table_Name + ' Drop Constraint ' + Constraint_Name
from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
order by Constraint_type

Answer (score 0):

You could select rows from the `dbo.sysobjects` table with `xtype in ('F', 'PK')` and, for each row, generate the appropriate `alter table` statement. However, I would first ask, why do you want to do this? Constraints are very important for a number of different reasons.

Comment: i want to remove all the contstraints and create all new constraints 
when ever i will remove pk then it will give me error that remove first fk that is main problme

Comment: How about just dropping all the FKs then re-creating them?

Answer (score 0):

You can find constraints listed in the sysobjects table:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype IN ('F', 'PK')
```

Use a cursor to loop through the relevant records, build an SQL statement in a string that will remove each constraint, and EXEC() the statement.